# Adicionar html com jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom quando quero adicionar um html na página usando `jQuery` eu faço assim:

```
$("body").html('ddd');
```

Porém dessa forma eu apago o conteúdo antigo, é possível eu adicionar o html no Body sem apagar o conteúdo da página?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aquilo que estás á procura é [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/), adiciona dentro do elemento depois de tudo:

```
$("body").append('ddd');
```

Ou [prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) que adiciona dentro do elemento mas antes de tudo:

```
$("body").prepend('ddd');
```

Exemplo:

```js
$("body").append('<p>Eu vou para depois do conteudo do body</p>');
$("body").prepend('<p>Eu vou para antes do conteudo do body</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h2>Eu vou estar no meio depois dos outros serem inseridos</h2>
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Sim, usando [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
$(seletor).append();
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método [append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) do jQuery

```
$( "body" ).append( "Seu texto" );
```

Comment: vlw muito obrigado